# "Mastering / crushing / playing" Steam game info for Borderlands 2

Tags: steam, borderlands-2

If you try viewing game info of a person playing Borderlands 2, it will show you "Mastering 1-52", "Crushing 1-9" or "Playing 1-11" and also "Dominating".

The first number means the playthrough number, and the second is the current quest number. But what do the words *Mastering*, *Crushing* and others mean?

Comment: Question was edited and doesn't appear to be an exact duplicate anymore, reopening...

Comment: If anybody knows the complete list of those "titles", I will surely get back to this question and mark your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure it's the following;

TITLE PLAYTHROUGH-QUEST

TITLE being just a set value based on how many quests the player has done (the higher you are, the more "badass" the title is).

PLAYTHROUGH being what number playthrough the player is on (1st time is one, 2nd playthrough is 2, etc etc).

QUEST being how many completed quests the player has done.

Basically just a quick status check you can do on your friends to see and compare (without going to achievements).

Also note that this occurs on Steam, Xbox 360 and PS3.

Comment: Do you happen to know all existing titles for this status thing?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the full list of title.